# Cannot mouse clicked on a record in the jtable that has been Search and filtered among many other records

Tags: java, jframe, javadb

I'm having an issue where, I cannot mouse click on a record in the jtable that has been searched and filtered. 
Let's assume, I have many records and i want to search/filter the record first and then mouse clicked on the filtered record for it to appear in the textField Boxes for deletion process. Thanks in Advance I need help badly.

My Table Before

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bee30.png]

My Table After Searched and filter, the row selected not appearing in the text field:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PeFhj.png]

```
    private void deleteBtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    try {
        Connection conn= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/KDatabase","koushal","456");
        Statement st= conn.createStatement();
        int row= jTableStaff.getSelectedRow();
        String value=(jTableStaff.getModel().getValueAt(row,0).toString());
        String query="delete from STAFFS where ID="+value;
        PreparedStatement statement =conn.prepareStatement(query);
        statement.executeUpdate();
        DefaultTableModel model= (DefaultTableModel)jTableStaff.getModel();
        model.setRowCount(0);
        showStaff(); 
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Deletion Sucessfull ");

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(DeleteManagerInterface.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}  

    private void jTableStaffMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                         
    int i=jTableStaff.getSelectedRow();
    TableModel model=jTableStaff.getModel();
    ID_TxtField.setText(model.getValueAt(i,0).toString());
    Name_TxtField.setText(model.getValueAt(i,1).toString());
}                                        

private void SearchingIDTxtFieldKeyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                                
    String userquery=SearchingIDTxtField.getText();
    DefaultTableModel model= (DefaultTableModel)jTableStaff.getModel();
    TableRowSorter<DefaultTableModel> sorter =new TableRowSorter<> (model);
    jTableStaff.setRowSorter(sorter);
    sorter.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter("(?i)"+userquery,0)); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

do this

```
DefaultTableModel mt = (DefaultTableModel)table.getModel();
String a = (String) mt.getValueAt(table.getSelectedRow(), 0);
String b =(String) mt.getValueAt(table.getSelectedRow(), 1);
String c =(String) mt.getValueAt(table.getSelectedRow(), 2);
```

then set the strings to textfields.

```
textfield.setText(a);
textfield1.setText(b);
textfield2.setText(c);
```

Comment: Sir, in which methods to write the 2 block codes you provide me? in jTableStaffMouseClicked or SearchingIDTxtFieldKeyReleased ?

Comment: I got error like this "Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String" when I put your provided block codes in the jTableStaffMouseClicked method.

Comment: Oh if you have integers... Then first you have to convert it into string to set text in a text field

Comment: The table has been "filtered". So you should use the getValueAt(...) method of the JTable, not the TableModel.